# How to detect if today or tomorrow is the 2nd or last Wed of the month in Java?

Tags: java, date

How to detect if today or tomorrow is the 2nd or last Wed of the month in Java ? Any sample code ?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: What's the standard answer for all things related to Date in Java?  Try JODA....

Comment: Try Joda, or Calendar if you have to.

Comment: Use java.time. (1) Get today from `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. (2) Get tomorrow form `today.plusDays(1)`. (3) Get the 2nd Wednesday of this month from `today.with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(2, DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY)`. (4) Get the last Wednesday from `today.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY)`. (5) Compare the dates using their `equals()` methods to determine whether today or tomorrow is equal to either the 2nd or the last Wednesday. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) (6) Realize that in case tomorrow happened to fall in the next month, it can neither be the 2nd nor the last Wednesday of that month, so we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Joda Time Library, which has DateTime class and all the utility methods needed like plusDays(int),plusWeeks(int)

Comment: This was a good (although not so elaborate) answer 12 years ago. Joda-Time has later been replaced by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the smart [Comment by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575387/how-to-detect-if-today-or-tomorrow-is-the-2nd-or-last-wed-of-the-month-in-java/76274263#comment134506537_4575387)…

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Edmonton" ) );
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays ( 1 );

LocalDate secondWed = today.with ( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth ( 2 , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) );
LocalDate lastWed = today.with ( TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth ( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) );

boolean eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth =
        Set.of ( today , tomorrow )
                .stream ( )
                .anyMatch (
                        Set.of ( secondWed , lastWed ) :: contains
                );
```

## *java.time*

In modern Java, we have the industry-leading *java.time* classes to do date-time handling.

To represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

Capture the current date. This involves a time zone; for any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault()
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Determine tomorrow's date.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Determine the second Wednesday of today's month. A `TemporalAdjuster` moves from one day to another. The utility class `TemporalAdjusters` contains several handy temporal adjusters. The `DayOfWeek` class defines enums objects for each day of the week.

```
LocalDate secondWed = 
    today.with( 
        TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 2 , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY )
    ) ;
```

And the last Wednesday of the month.

```
LocalDate lastWed = 
    today.with(
        TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY )
    ) ;
```

The date for `tomorrow` could land in the following month. I assume you want to consider only the current month, the month containing `today`.

See if today matches either:

```
boolean todayIsEitherSecondOrLastWed = 
    today.isEqual( secondWed ) || 
    today.isEqual( lastWed ) ;
```

Ditto for tomorrow.

```
boolean tomorrowIsEitherSecondOrLastWed = 
    tomorrow.isEqual( secondWed ) || 
    tomorrow.isEqual( lastWed ) ;
```

Final comparison.

```java
boolean eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth = 
    todayIsEitherSecondOrLastWed || tomorrowIsEitherSecondOrLastWed ;
```

We could use [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) collections of our dates.

```java
boolean eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth =
    Set.of( secondWed , lastWed ).contains( today ) ||
    Set.of( secondWed , lastWed ).contains( tomorrow ) ;
```

Or we could get fancy, using streams and lambdas to compare two sets. Fun, but not necessarily better.

```java
boolean eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth =
        Set.of ( today , tomorrow )
                .stream ( )
                .anyMatch (
                        ( LocalDate localDate ) -> Set.of ( secondWed , lastWed ).contains ( localDate )
                );
```

More briefly, using a method reference:

```java
boolean eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth =
        Set.of ( today , tomorrow )
                .stream ( )
                .anyMatch (
                        Set.of ( secondWed , lastWed ) :: contains
                );
```

### Full code example

```java
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "Africa/Tunis" ) );
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays ( 1 );

LocalDate secondWed = today.with ( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth ( 2 , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) );
LocalDate lastWed = today.with ( TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth ( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) );

boolean eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth =
        Set.of ( today , tomorrow )
                .stream ( )
                .anyMatch (
                        Set.of ( secondWed , lastWed ) :: contains
                );

System.out.println ( "today = " + today + " | tomorrow = " + tomorrow );
System.out.println ( "secondWed = " + secondWed + " | lastWed = " + lastWed );
System.out.println ( "eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth = " + eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesdayOfCurrentMonth );
```

When run:

```
today = 2023-05-18 | tomorrow = 2023-05-19
secondWed = 2023-05-10 | lastWed = 2023-05-31
eitherTodayOrTomorrowIsSecondOrLastWednesday = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You having a problem with street-cleaning?

Calendar will tell you if it's a Wednesday (`day.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) == WEDNESDAY`) and the day of the month.  If it's a Wednesday between the 8th and 15th, it's the second of the month; between 22nd and the 29th, it's the fourth.

Comment: So it seems I've to do some calculation.

Comment: The fourth isn't necessarily the last. A month can contain five Wednesdays.

Comment: Ah, I put in the street-cleaning rules in *my* neighborhood: as I wrote, the first and the fourth.  If you just want the last, take the number of days in the current month, subtract 7, compare to current date...

Answer (score 0):

Use math ceiling function.
After having found that it is a wednesday you use ceiling(DayOfTheMonth/7).
The result tells you the how maniest occurence of the wednesday in this month this is.

Comment: I think this needs some more details to it